# MYSQL : help with count row function

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve the number of rows in my `qrec_id` in my table `tbl_link_qa`, which has values in them.

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(qrec_id) from tbl_link_qa")or die(mysql_error());
```

But this doesn't seem to give any output.

----updated:

$x=0;

mysql_query("SELECT COUNT * from tbl_link_qa WHERE qrec_id != $x");

Comment: `mysql_query()` alone will not give any output. Check out the manual page for a full working example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: you have to get that value **exactly the same way** you're getting any other data. why not to apply code you already used for other mysql operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query instead to get number of columns with not null values:

```
SELECT SUM(qrec_id IS NOT NULL) FROM tbl_link_qa
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_link_qa WHERE qrec_id IS NOT NULL
```

and @Gordon script

Comment: or maybe ´SELECT SUM(qrec_id IS NULL) AS available, count(*) AS total FROM tbl_link_qa´ depends what it means if the field is `NULL`

Comment: Thank you! I got it now :) I just have to figure out my next step. Turning "1 of 5" to "2 of 5" when I click the next button and "1 of 5" back when I click my previous button.

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't give any output because all it's doing is sending the query to the database.  It's not actually collecting the results.

You need to assign the result of mysql_query() to a variable.

```
<?php
if ($result = mysql_query ('select count(*) from wherever;'))
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
    var_dump ($row);
}
else
    die ('some error message');
?>
```

Comment: It gave this off. array(1) { ["count(*)"]=> string(2) "87" } I need to get the number of affected rows in qrec_id field which contained values.

Comment: I need to get this code to be able to come off with a "1 of n questions available". The n is the number of rows that contained values in qrec_id that had yet to have any corresponding answers to them.

Comment: array(1) { ["count(*)"]=> string(2) "59" } it gave me this instead.

Comment: It's returning an array. You do know how to access array members, right?  If not, it's all there in the PHP manual.

Comment: I got it :) mysql_fetch_assoc(). I just need to figure out how it's gonna be from "1 of 5" to "2 of 5" when I click next

Answer (score 1):

You have a full example in the manual page:

http://es.php.net/mysql_query

See example #2.